# Kotlin unit testing high order function in data class fails when passing lambda argument

Tags: kotlin, junit, junit5

```kotlin
data class DataSample(val name: String, val exec: () -> Unit = {})
```

I am trying to understand why the following test would fail:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `testing data fails`() {
    val dataOne = DataSample("the_same") {
    }
    val dataTwo = DataSample("the_same") {
    }
    assertEquals(dataOne, dataTwo)
}
```

and the following would pass:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `testing data pass`() {
    val dataOne = DataSample("the_same")
    val dataTwo = DataSample("the_same")
    assertEquals(dataOne, dataTwo)
}
```

The test will pass when the lambda is omitted and it fails when one is provided.

Comment: did you find a solution to test this class with lambda?

Comment: @Sam you have to make sure the lambda has the same signature therefore you can't initialise them separately like the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since instances of data classes are compared member by member the first test succeeds because “the same“ is equal to “the same“ and the default value for exec is `{}` which is equal to itself. In the second test you give each instance its own lambda which are not equal to each other even though they behave equally. Thus, comparing `dataOne` and `dataTwo` fails.

Comment: so what's the best way to compare the object with lambda?